# SQL Query Using Exists

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to find values from two tables using Exists or Not Exists either option will be sufficient.

The two tables are Worker and Assignment, I'm trying to find the names of the workers not assigned to Building 546. The issue is the workers are assigned to more than one building so in one example a worker is assigned to 546 and 423, so they should not show in the return, but they do.

Table Worker:

```
Worker_ID | Worker_name
     1411 | Beth 
     1521 | Amber 
     1351 | Caren 
     1345 | Mike 
     1456 | Austin 
     1457 | Steven 
     1744 | Sam
```

Table Assignment:

```
Worker_ID | Building_Num
     1411 | 546
     1521 | 423
     1351 | 423
     1345 | 431
     1456 | 421
     1457 | 465
     1744 | 423
     1411 | 423
     1521 | 451
     1351 | 428
     1345 | 421
     1456 | 427
     1457 | 426
     1744 | 546
```

I tried the following:

```
SELECT W.Worker_NAME, B.BLDG_ID
FROM W_WORKER W INNER JOIN A_ASSIGNMENT A ON W.WORKER_ID = A.WORKER_ID 
                INNER JOIN B_BUILDING B ON B.BLDG_ID = A.BLDG_ID
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT  DISTINCT W.WORKER_ID
              FROM W_WORKER W INNER JOIN A_ASSIGNMENT A ON W.WORKER_ID = A.WORKER_ID
              WHERE A.BLDG_ID <> 435)
```

Example of a Nested Query That works:

```
SELECT W.Worker_NAME
    FROM W_WORKER W INNER JOIN A_ASSIGNMENT A ON W.WORKER_ID = A.WORKER_ID 
                    INNER JOIN B_BUILDING B ON B.BLDG_ID = A.BLDG_ID
    WHERE B.BLDG_ID <> ( SELECT  DISTINCT B.BLDG_ID 
                  FROM W_WORKER W INNER JOIN A_ASSIGNMENT A ON W.WORKER_ID = A.WORKER_ID 
                                  INNER JOIN B_BUILDING B ON B.BLDG_ID = A.BLDG_ID
                  WHERE B.BLDG_ID = 546)
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: SELECT W.Worker_NAME, B.BLDG_ID
FROM W_WORKER W INNER JOIN A_ASSIGNMENT A ON W.WORKER_ID = A.WORKER_ID 
    INNER JOIN B_BUILDING B ON B.BLDG_ID = A.BLDG_ID
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT  DISTINCT W.WORKER_ID
     FROM W_WORKER W INNER JOIN A_ASSIGNMENT A ON W.WORKER_ID = A.WORKER_ID
     WHERE A.BLDG_ID <> 435)

Comment: Or if you scroll down to the bottem of my snippet it shows the code I am trying and the successful nested query that returns te correct value.

Comment: you only want to get the `workers` detail so you don't join to the building but filter `not exists` against the assignment if the worker has at least building 546 assigned to him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NOT EXISTS`

```
select *
from workers w
where
not exists (   -- if a worker is also assigned to building 546 then don't return
select 1 from 
assignment a
where
a.worker_id = w.worker_id   -- this will match all assignments for a worker
and building_num = 546    -- but if there is at least an assignment to building 546 then exclude the worker

)
```

Comment: That worked! I am curious why you didn't join the tables, I have only worked with two tables by directly joining them together via Inner our Outer Join?

Comment: `JOIN` won't give you the best results as you can have more than one building assignment. `NOT EXISTS` is appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Using EXCEPT is a better and faster option.

```
SELECT Worker_name from w_worker where worker_id in

(
Select worker_id from W_worker
EXCEPT
Select worker_id from W_worker
  where building_num= 546
)
```

You basically eliminate the workers of building 546 this way.

(Sorry for formatting..on cell phone)

Comment: why not use `NOT EXISTS` ?

Comment: This does work, unfortunately, we are forced to using exists as a way of trying to use it in different settings. My nested query at the bottom of the snippet works, but I have to try and replicate it using exists.

Comment: Because set operations in SQL are the fastest.

Comment: set operations? you are even using `IN` how would that make it faster?

Comment: In is a mandate since the output requires a different field. To solve it differently would require a join operation. Any way SQL Server is smart enough to convert IN into EXISTS.

Comment: Usage of SET operations is a more elegant way to solve such problems, IMO and hence pointed the same to OP. Since as per him the requirement is to do it using EXISTS, it wiuld require a different query.

Comment: suggest you back to schooling. You don't even know the difference between `IN` and `EXISTS`

Comment: Thank you I am good. But you are a really obnoxious person. When you get out of your a**, do google on the internal conversion SQL engine does to a IN operator to EXISTS.

Comment: FYI... coz i'm pretty sure you don't know... `IN` matches the columns BUT will READ ALL ROWS until the end... `EXISTS` matches the columns BUT will END if it finds the 1st MATCH.

Comment: For other readers, FYI..in all modern RDBMS, the engine is smart enough to make choices for you. So unless your query is horribly poor, it will fix it- like in this case. SQL Server treats IN just like EXISTS (atleast for simple queries). Although, “theoretically” EXISTS is faster.

Comment: also FYI... `IN` will only be faster if there is a definite list to match i.e. `IN (1,2,3,4,5)  vs IN(select field from table)`

Comment: Nope. It’s not just for literals. If there is a significant cost difference between the two operations, the conversion takes place.